# SQL Server: Hex values padded with zeros and bytes out of order

Tags: sql-server, hex

I'm working on a database that has a `VARBINARY(255)` column that doesn't make sense to me. Depending on the length of the value, the value is either numbers or words.

For whatever number is stored, it is a 4-byte hex string `0x00000000`, but reads left to right while the bytes read right to left. So for a number such as `255`, it is `0xFF000000` and for a number such as `745`, it is `0xE9020000`. This is the part that I do not understand, why is it stored that way instead of `0x02E9`, `0x2E9` or `0x000002E9`?

When it comes to words, each character is stored as a 4-byte hex string just like above. Something like a space is stored as `0x20000000`, but a word like `Sensor`  it is `0x53000000650000006E000000730000006F00000072000000` instead of just `0x53656E736F72`.

Can anyone explain to me why the data is stored in this way? Is everything represented as 4-byte strings because the numbers stored can be the full 4-bytes while text is padded with zeros for consistency? Why are the zeros padded to the right of the value? Why are the values stored with the 4th byte first and 1st  byte last?

If none of this makes sense from an SQL standpoint, I suppose it is possible that the data is being provided this way from the client application which I do not have access to the source on. Could that be the case?

Lastly, I would like to create a report that includes this column, but converted to the correct numbers or words. Is there a simpler and more performant method than using substrings, trims, and recursion?

Comment: This is not a sql server issue. The values stored are those provided by the application and their interpretation is embedded in the application logic. You might want to take some time to read about endianness (little vs. big) and about strings (ascii vs unicode). Since the datatype is binary, it might be that all values are direct memory images of a structure used to access this information in the app - that might be why you see extra bytes. But the only way to know is to look at the app logic.

Comment: @SMor Good point on the little vs big endianness, that was a big help! I have since worked the values from LSB to MSB, stripped the padded zeros (in the case of stored words instead of numbers), and now have words as my final result! Thanks for the pointers!

Answer (score 0):

With the help of Smor in the comments above, I can now answer my own questions.

The client application provides the 4-byte strings and the database just takes them as they fit within the column's `VARBINARY(255)` data type and length. Since the application is providing the values in a little-endian format, they are stored in that way within the database with the least significant byte first and the most significant byte last. Being that most values are smaller than the static 4-byte length, the values are padded with zeros to the right to fit the 4-byte requirement.

Now as to my question of the report, this is what I came up with:

```
CASE 
    WHEN LEN(ByteValue) <= 4 
        THEN CAST(CAST(CAST(REVERSE(ByteValue) AS VARBINARY(4)) AS INT) AS VARCHAR(12))
    ELSE CAST(CONVERT(VARBINARY(255),REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(255),ByteValue,1),'000000',''),1) AS VARCHAR(100))
END AS PlainValue
```

In my particular case, only numbers are stored as just 4-byte or less values while words are stored as much longer values. This allows me to break the smaller values into numbers while longer values are broken down into words.

Using `CASE WHEN` I can specify that only data 4-bytes or less needs the `REVERSE()` function as it is the easiest way to convert the little-endian format to the big-endian format that SQL is looking for when converting from hex to integers. Due to the `REVERSE()` function returning a `NVARCHAR` datatype, I then have to convert that back to `VARBINARY`, then to `INT`, then to `VARCHAR` to match the datatype of the second case datatype.

Any string longer than 4-bytes, used specifically for words, falls under the `ELSE` part and allows me to strip the extra zeros from the hex value so I get just the first byte of each 4-byte long character (the only part that matters in my situation). By converting the hex string to `VARCHAR`, I can then easily remove the 6 repeating zeros using the `REPLACE()` function. With the zeros gone, converting the string back to `VARBINARY` allows converting to `VARCHAR` to be done with ease.